# How to check if a word contains one letter from another string

Tags: python, python-re

I am working on a program in which I check if a word for example: "Cat" contains a letter. To this I have tried using `if letter in word` but it doesn't work when I try to check for multiple letters in a word as it checks if the word contains every single letter. I have also tried using re like this

```
import re
bad_letters = "AKS"
word = "Sanctuary"

if re.match(bad_letters, word):
    print("It is a match")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `if any(char in word for char in bad_letters):`

Comment: if you care about performance, don't use regex. just iterate over the word and check if there's a bad letter in the char. edit: see Paul M.'s comment

Comment: @PaulM. Looks like the OP wants a case-insensitive match.

Comment: `if re.search(f'[{bad_letters}]', word, re.IGNORECASE): print("It is a match")`

Comment: `if set(word.lower()).intersection(bad_letters.lower()):`.

Comment: Non global match with regex might have better performance in some instances...

Comment: Are you looking to match if a word contains 3 letters "A", "K", or "S" -- or rather are you interested in checking if a word contains "AKS" (example "yaks")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regexp solution:

```
import re
bad_letters = "AKS"
word = "Sanctuary"

if re.search(f"[{bad_letters}]", word, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("It is a match")
```

It is claimed that it *might* be slower than avoiding a regexp.  In this example, that is indeed true, but only fairly marginally.

```
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'bad_letters = "AKSaks"; word = "Sanctuary"' 'any(char in word for char in bad_letters)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.468 usec per loop
```

```
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'bad_letters = "AKS"; word = "Sanctuary"; import re' 're.search(f"[{bad_letters}]", word, re.IGNORECASE)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.622 usec per loop
```

In fact, some of the time that is measured there is constructing the pattern `'[AKS]'` from the bad characters `'AKS'` and compiling the regexp.  If this is taken out of the timing measurement, then the precompiled regexp wins easily.

```
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'import re; bad_letters = "AKS"; matcher=re.compile(f"[{bad_letters}]", re.IGNORECASE).search; word = "Sanctuary"' 'matcher(word)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.167 usec per loop
```

Comment: @superbrain I was already on the case when you posted that. Now updated...

Comment: Oh and I think you're mistaken about the compiling of the regexp making a difference. In 9999999 of the 10000000 loops, I think it'll not get compiled but taken from the cache.

Comment: Edited to deal with the flag. What you say about the cache sounds reasonable, but then I am not sure if the time taken is the string formatting of the pattern or retrieving from cache (only a dictionary lookup surely!), and I don't have time to investigate further just now.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to also know wich letter match:

```
bad_letters="AKS".lower()
word="Sanctuary".lower()

for blet in bad_letters:
    for let in word:
        if blet==let:
            print("It is a match:",let)
            break
```

Comment: ekhumoro's `set` solution from comments below OP return elegantly all the matches

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to check for bad letters in one string so you could do:

```
    word = "hello"
    string = "EH"
    for letter in string:
        if letter.lower() in word.lower():
            print('success')
        else:
            print('failure')
```